# Finding the number of occurrences of keys and the positions of first occurrences of keys by CUDA Thrust

Tags: cuda, thrust

Say I have a vector of keys

```
thrust::device_vector<int> keys(10); 
keys[0] = 51; // -----> 
keys[1] = 51; 
keys[2] = 72; // -----> 
keys[3] = 72; 
keys[4] = 72; 
keys[5] = 103; //-----> 
keys[6] = 103; 
keys[7] = 504; // ------> 
keys[8] = 504 
keys[9] = 504 ;
```

I already know before hand that there are `4` distinct key values in 
this vector. I want to populate the two device arrays 
`pidx[4]` and `pnum[4]`.

1. The `pidx` array gives me the first position of each distinct key in the 
   keys vector, namely the positions marked with `---->` in the code snippet above. So, in this example, I should have `pidx[4] = {0, 2, 5, 7}`.
2. The `pnum` array gives me the number of occurrences of each key. So, in this example, I should have 
   `pnum[4] = {2, 3, 2, 3}` .

How would one perform the above operation with CUDA Thrust?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not the optimal solution, but I can't figure out a better way.

```
// Use `unique` to grab the distinct values
thrust::device_vector<int> values(4);
thrust::unique_copy( keys.begin(), keys.end(), values.begin() );

// For each of the values use `count` to get the frequencies
for ( int i = 4; i != 0; --i )
    pnum[i] = thrust::count( keys.begin(), keys.end(), values[i] );

// Use prefix sum to get the indices
thrust::exclusive_scan( pnum.begin(), pnum.end(), pidx.begin() );
```

Answer (score 1):

This solution assumes that your list of keys is already sorted.  If it's not, then just add another step at the beginning to sort the list.

```
// generate a list of indices to correspond with the key array
thrust::device_vector<int> values(numKeys);
thrust::sequence(values.begin(), values.end());

// perform an inclusive scan to determine the minimum index for each unique key
thrust::equal_to<int> binaryPred;
thrust::minimum<int> binaryOp;
thrust::inclusive_scan_by_key(keys.begin(), keys.end(), values.begin(), values.begin(), binaryPred, binaryOp);

// find the unique indices
thrust::unique(values.begin(), values.end());
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question is about two different problems:

1. Finding the number of occurrencies of elements inside a vector;
2. Finding the position of the first occurrence for each key.

It appears to me that the two points above are recognized in none of the other provided answers.

**Problem #1** amounts at constructing the histogram of the sequence, see https://code.google.com/p/thrust/source/browse/examples/histogram.cu. The classical solution to this problem is to first sort the keys by `thrust::sort` and then performing a `thrust::reduce_by_key` to calculate the number of occurrencies. This has been already recognized at [Counting occurences of numbers in cuda array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7573900/counting-occurences-of-numbers-in-cuda-array) and [thrust count occurence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11553839/thrust-count-occurence).

**Problem #2** is an application of `thrust::unique_by_key` and `thrust::sequence`.

Here is a fully worked example:

```
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <thrust/reduce.h>
#include <thrust/random.h>
#include <thrust/sort.h>

/********/
/* MAIN */
/********/
int main()
{
    /**************************/
    /* SETTING UP THE PROBLEM */
    /**************************/

    const int N = 20;           // --- Number of elements

    // --- Random uniform integer distribution between 0 and 4
    thrust::default_random_engine rng;
    thrust::uniform_int_distribution<int> dist(0, 4);

    // --- Keys allocation and initialization
    thrust::device_vector<int> d_keys(N);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < d_keys.size(); i++) d_keys[i] = dist(rng);

    /****************/
    /* THE APPROACH */
    /****************/

    thrust::device_vector<int> d_values(N, 1);
    thrust::sort(d_keys.begin(), d_keys.end());

    thrust::reduce_by_key(d_keys.begin(), d_keys.end(), thrust::constant_iterator<int>(1), d_keys.begin(), d_values.begin());

    printf("Keys\n");
    for (int i=0; i<N; i++) std::cout << d_keys[i] << " " << d_values[i] << "\n";
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

as an alternative solution, you can try [Arrayfire](http://www.accelereyes.com/arrayfire/c/)
library. It has special functions for that sort of problems:

```
   float keys[] = {51,51,72,72,72,103,103,504,504,504};      
   int N = sizeof(keys) / sizeof(int);

   array input(N, 1, keys);
   array values, pidx, locations;
   // unique elements in a vector and their indicies 
   setunique(values, pidx, locations, input);

   // # of unique elements
   int n_unique = pidx.elements();
   array pnum = zeros(n_unique); // empty array

   gfor(array i, n_unique) // parallel for loop
      // count the # of occurrences for each key
      pnum(i) = sum(locations == i);

   print(pidx);           
   print(pnum);
```

output:

pidx =
           0.0000 
           2.0000 
           5.0000 
           7.0000

pnum =
           2.0000 
           3.0000 
           2.0000 
           3.0000