# thrust count occurence

Tags: c++, cuda, reduce, thrust

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Counting occurences of numbers in cuda array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7573900/counting-occurences-of-numbers-in-cuda-array)

Is there a way to use Thrust or CUDA to count occurrences for the duplicates in an array?

For example:
If I have a device vector

```
{11, 11, 9, 1, 3, 11, 1, 2, 9, 1, 11}
```

I should get

```
1:3, 2:1, 3:1, 9:2, 11:4
```

If Thrust cannot do that, how can I use a kernel to do that?

Thanks! I am doing a concentration calculation. That's why I am asking this question.
Assume that there are 100000 particles in the domain which has `nx * ny * nz` cells, I need to calculate the concentration of each cell (how many particles in each cell).

My kernel is this

```
__global__ void concentration_kernel(float3* posPtr, uint* device_cons) 
{
    __shared__ uint cache[256];
    uint x = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;
    uint y = threadIdx.y + blockIdx.y * blockDim.y;
    uint offset = x + y * blockDim.x * gridDim.x; 

    float3 posf3 = posPtr[offset];//make_float3(43.5,55,0.66);//
    uint cellIndex = (uint)(posf3.z+1)*153*110 + (uint)(posf3.y)*153 + (uint)posf3.x;

    cache[threadIdx.x] = device_cons[cellIndex];
    __syncthreads();
    uint a = cache[threadIdx.x];
    a++;
    cache[threadIdx.x] = a;
    __syncthreads();

    device_cons[cellIndex] = cache[threadIdx.x]; 
}
```

Comment: Damn! just found histogram.cu can do this, but I am wondering how can I use cuda kernel to implement this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can first sort the vector using [thrust::sort](http://docs.thrust.googlecode.com/hg/group__sorting.html#ga01621fff7b6eb24fb68944cc2f10af6a) and then use [thrust::reduce_by_key](http://docs.thrust.googlecode.com/hg/group__reductions.html#ga1fd25c0e5e4cc0a6ab0dcb1f7f13a2ad). However, you also need to create a new vector (called `values`) of `1`'s (and of the same length as your sorted vector) after sort. These values will be added up to get the counts:

> `reduce_by_key` is a generalization of `reduce` to key-value pairs.
> For each group of consecutive keys in the range `[keys_first, keys_last)`
> that are equal, `reduce_by_key` copies the first element of the group to
> the `keys_output`. The corresponding values in the range are reduced using
> the `plus` and the result copied to `values_output`.

Comment: Thanks! I am doing concentration calculation.my code is this

Comment: `__global__ void concentration_kernel(float3* posPtr, uint* device_cons) 
>{
 > __shared__ uint cache[256];
  uint x = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;
  uint y = threadIdx.y + blockIdx.y * blockDim.y;
  uint offset = x + y * blockDim.x * gridDim.x; 
  
  float3 posf3 = posPtr[offset]
  uint cellIndex = (uint)(posf3.z+1)*153*110 + 
     (uint)(posf3.y)*153 + (uint)posf3.x;
     
  cache[threadIdx.x] = device_cons[cellIndex];
  __syncthreads();
  uint a = cache[threadIdx.x];
  a++;
  cache[threadIdx.x] = a;
  __syncthreads();
  device_cons[cellIndex] = cache[threadIdx.x]; 
}`

Comment: I did some test, it doesn't give me correct result

Comment: better put this code into the question, looks cryptic here

Comment: There's no need to use a container to store the extra 1s; a `constant_iterator` works just as well and doesn't create extra storage.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a combination of `thrust::unique` and `thrust::binary_search` to find duplicates. You won't be able to do it in place using this approach, but it can be done just using thrust code.

Comment: Thanks! I figured it out in Thrust, but still confused how to do that using cuda kernel

Comment: 2 approaches I can see: brute force or roll your own binary search. In the second one you'd need to sort the input first.